# In windows 7 how can I run an executable on a remote PC and wait-for and get the results?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, remote-execution

I have a build PC that is going to deploy executables to another PC on the network. I have a mapped network drive to do the copying, but I could also use FTP. So the copying is fairly trivial.

Once those executables are copied I want to instruct the remote PC to run the application. Once the application completes some logs will be generated. The Build PC needs to know when the remote PC has finished so that it can collect the logs from the network drive.

How can I achieve this? - currently my build scripts are in VBScript.

Comment: By communicating the completion. You could use a PowerShell remote session from the build PC to run the script on the remote PC. You could use files to indicate any kind of completing either by letting the build PC or remote PC push/pull. You could involve a database and watch for something that is written to it. You could let your build PC watch the remote EventLog and write to the Log when your script completes. There are probably more alternatives available.

Comment: Is it suitable for you to send commands remotely through psexec?

Comment: Maybe my understanding is not correct, but try looking at module *subprocess* in python and its method `communicate()`

Comment: @Seth Thanks for that - never really used power shell, i think I need to install this to get it to work, is that correct? (I think PS1 is installed, but need PS3). I was hoping for a more built-in option or something simpler.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio ohhh...that looks very promising! - infact probably exactly what I need. I will need to trial it out - but an interactive command line sounds like it can be run via my VBScript, do you think that is correct?

Comment: @Pavel This also looks possible - don't really want to install Python, but it would probably only be a small-ish python script. thanks :)

Comment: An updated Windows 7 would have (at least) PowerShell 2 available which already supports PS-Sessions. I'm not sure about PS1. But you would need to actually allow remote sessions to make it work. In regards to this `psexec` might be more suitable and yes, you should be able to use it through VBScript or you could go for a mix to make it easier to understand (IMHO). ;)

Comment: @seth and others. Thanks very much. If any of you want to include your suggestions as answers I will happily mark them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your kind of scenario there are a lot of different approaches you could be going for. Examples would include:

- Using files to indicate whenever your script completed (using some form of push/pull mechanism on either end)
- Using a network for direct communication (could be hard with VBScript)
- Using a database instead of a file and base push/pull mechanism on that
- Watching the EventLog of the remote machine and writing to it if the scripts completes.
- Using a Remote-Session of some form (e.g. PowerShell)

In my opinion the last option is probably the most comfortable one. For PowerShell this would mean you need to enable PowerShell remoting on the remote machine and would establish a connection from your build server to directly execute commands on the remote host.

There are severals guides available on how to set this up ([Quick Guide to PowerShell v2 Remoting with PSSession](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2269.quick-guide-to-powershell-v2-remoting-with-pssession.aspx)) and after the initial Setup it would be as easy as creating a new Session (`New-PSSession`/`Enter-PSSession`) and using it (`Enter-PSSession`/`Invoke-Command`).

If you don't want to rely on this you could also take [`psexec`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx), which is part of the Sysinternals tools, into consideration. Again you would need to make sure that you're able to reach the remote machine on certain ports but it could be easier to use this in combination with VBScript (Original Suggestion by Zumo de Vidrio).